# AMPScript function to display day of the week

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am working with AMPScript and formatting out dates. Is there a function that will return the actual day of the week when pulling in the date parameter?

Currently working with the following to format the actual date: `%%=Format(@pickupDeadline,"MM/dd/yyyy")=%%` but want to add the day of the week to it within the text of the email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you want to display say Monday when your `@pickupDeadline` is on Monday, you can simply do:

`%%=Format(@pickupDeadline,"dddd")=%%`

I hope this helps.